# Undefined reference compiling OpenFP

Tags: c++, c, linux, linker, libm

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I am trying to compile this project [OpenFP](http://open-fp.sourceforge.net/download.html). Issue is when after I run "configure" shell and use "make" to compile it I receive following error.

> /usr/bin/ld: openfp_extract-fft.o: undefined reference to symbol 'cos@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
>   //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make[1]: *** [openfp_extract] Error 1
>   make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/murtaza/Desktop/openfp-1.3.2'
>   make: *** [all] Error 2

The problem I believe is compiler unable to implicitly linking to "libm", but I really don't understand where to append -lm to make it work. I've tried on different locations in "makefile.am". But each time after configuration I get the same results. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The error seems a missing symbol in your glibc: **undefined reference to symbol 'cos@@GLIBC_2.2.5'** why do you thing it's a linking issue related to libm? It might be that the OpenFP project was meant to be linked with a different (older?) version of the glibc

Comment: It was the same error as I explained. glibc doesn't implicitly link to libm. and also order of placing -lm is important. You should place it in the very end. After configuration when it produced the Makefile, I appended -lm flag in LDFLAG variable. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the same error as I explained. glibc doesn't implicitly link to libm. and also order of placing -lm is important. You should place it in the very end. After configuration when it produced the Makefile, I appended -lm flag in LDFLAG variable. It worked